# React: Cannot read property 'parts' of undefined

Tags: reactjs

In my project I can add an object through the form, in my case is a dialogue. As you can see from the picture the object (new dialogue) is successfully added to the golobal object.

[image]

However, when I try to go to this specific dialogue using its ID 'dialogue3', for example, /dialogue/dialogueID the following error is thrown.

[image]

**What can cause this issue? This is my code, that is responsible for adding new dialogues.**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';
import Fab from '@material-ui/core/Fab';
import AddIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Add';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

const styles = theme => ({
  container: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column'
  },
  textField: {
    marginLeft: theme.spacing.unit,
    marginRight: theme.spacing.unit,
    width: 200,
    display: 'block'
  },
  dense: {
    marginTop: 19
  },
  menu: {
    width: 200
  }
});

const speakers = [
  {
    value: 1,
    label: 'speaker 1'
  },
  {
    value: 2,
    label: 'speaker 2'
  }
];

const newField = {
  id: 'dialogue3',
  parts: []
};

class NewDialogueForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      audio: '',
      speaker: 1,
      text: '',
      prompt: '',
      helperFirst: '',
      helperTarget: '',
      translation: ''
    };
    this.addMoreFields = this.addMoreFields.bind(this);
    this.submitForm = this.submitForm.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange = name => event => {
    this.setState({ [name]: event.target.value });
  };

  addMoreFields() {
    newField.parts.push({
      text: this.state.text,
      speaker: this.state.speaker,
      audio: this.state.audio,
      prompt: this.state.prompt,
      helperFirst: this.state.helperFirst,
      helperTarget: this.state.helperTarget,
      translation: this.state.translation
    });
    console.log(newField);
    this.setState({
      audio: '',
      text: '',
      speaker: 1,
      prompt: '',
      helperFirst: '',
      helperTarget: '',
      translation: ''
    });
  }

  submitForm() {
    this.props.saveDialogue(newField);
  }

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    //console.log(this.state.dialogues);
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>New Dialogue Form</h1>

        <form className={classes.container} noValidate autoComplete="off">
          <TextField
            id="filled-select-speakers"
            select
            label="Select"
            className={classes.textField}
            value={this.state.speaker}
            onChange={this.handleChange('speaker')}
            SelectProps={{
              MenuProps: {
                className: classes.menu
              }
            }}
            helperText="Please select a speaker"
            margin="normal"
            variant="filled"
          >
            {speakers.map(option => (
              <MenuItem key={option.value} value={option.value}>
                {option.label}
              </MenuItem>
            ))}
          </TextField>
          <TextField
            id="text"
            label="Text"
            className={classes.textField}
            value={this.state.text}
            onChange={this.handleChange('text')}
            margin="normal"
          />
          <TextField
            id="audio"
            label="Audio"
            className={classes.textField}
            value={this.state.audio}
            onChange={this.handleChange('audio')}
            margin="normal"
          />
          <TextField
            id="translation"
            label="Translation"
            className={classes.textField}
            value={this.state.translation}
            onChange={this.handleChange('translation')}
            margin="normal"
          />
          <TextField
            id="prompt"
            label="Prompt"
            className={classes.textField}
            value={this.state.prompt}
            onChange={this.handleChange('prompt')}
            margin="normal"
          />
          <TextField
            id="helperFirst"
            label="Helper first"
            className={classes.textField}
            value={this.state.helperFirst}
            onChange={this.handleChange('helperFirst')}
            margin="normal"
          />
          <TextField
            id="helperTarget"
            label="Helper target"
            className={classes.textField}
            value={this.state.helperTarget}
            onChange={this.handleChange('helperTarget')}
            margin="normal"
          />
        </form>
        <Fab color="primary" aria-label="Add" className={classes.fab}>
          <AddIcon onClick={this.addMoreFields} />
        </Fab>
        <Button
          variant="contained"
          color="primary"
          onClick={this.submitForm}
          className={classes.button}
        >
          Primary
        </Button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withStyles(styles)(NewDialogueForm);
```

**This is the code that responsible for routing.**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import BubbleSpeechFrame from './BubbleSpeechFrame';
import lines from './inputData';
import NewDialogueForm from './NewDialogueForm';
import { Route, Switch, BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { dialogues: lines };
    this.findDialogue = this.findDialogue.bind(this);
    this.saveDialogue = this.saveDialogue.bind(this);
  }

  findDialogue(id) {
    return this.state.dialogues.find(function(dialogue) {
      return dialogue.id === id;
    });
  }

  saveDialogue(newDialogue) {
    this.setState({ dialogues: [...this.state.dialogues, newDialogue] });
    console.log(this.state.dialogues);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div id="cont">
          <BrowserRouter>
            <Switch>
              <Route
                exact
                path="/dialogue/new"
                render={routeProps => (
                  <NewDialogueForm
                    saveDialogue={this.saveDialogue}
                    dialogues={this.state.dialogues}
                    {...routeProps}
                  />
                )}
              />
              <Route
                exact
                path="/dialogue/:id"
                render={routeProps => (
                  <BubbleSpeechFrame
                    lines={this.findDialogue(routeProps.match.params.id)}
                  />
                )}
              />
            </Switch>
          </BrowserRouter>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**This is lines array which I try to populate with new created objcts.**

```
const lines = [
  {
    id: 'dialogue1',
    parts: [
      {
        text: `как дела?`,
        audio: 'audio/аудио1.mp3',
        prompt: '',
        speaker: 1,
        id: 1
      },
      {
        text: 'у меня все хорошо, а как ты?',
        audio: 'audio/аудио2.mp3',
        prompt: 'Say that: I am OK, how about you?',
        speaker: 2,
        id: 2,
        helpers: [
          {
            word_mother: "I'm all right",
            word_target: 'У меня все хорошо'
          },
          {
            word_mother: 'And you?',
            word_target: 'А как ты?'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        text: 'у меня тоже неплохо, кстати а что ты делаешь в субботу',
        audio: 'audio/аудио3.mp3',
        prompt: '',
        speaker: 1,
        id: 3,
        helpers: [
          {
            word_mother: 'Not bad',
            word_target: 'неплохо'
          },
          {
            word_mother: 'By the way',
            word_target: 'Кстати'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        text: 'в субботу у меня футбол, а что?',
        audio: 'audio/аудио4.mp3',
        speaker: 2,
        prompt: 'Say that: I have football on Saturday, why are you asking?',
        id: 4,
        helpers: [
          {
            word_mother: 'Why are you asking?',
            word_target: 'А что?'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        text: 'Просто я хотел пригласить тебя на день рождения',
        audio: 'audio/аудио5.mp3',
        speaker: 1,
        prompt: '',
        id: 5,
        helpers: [
          {
            word_mother: 'Just',
            word_target: 'Просто'
          },
          {
            word_mother: 'Wanted',
            word_target: 'Хотел (past simple form)'
          },
          {
            word_mother: 'To invite',
            word_target: 'Пригласить'
          },
          {
            word_mother: 'Birthday',
            word_target: 'День рождения'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        text:
          'Ты знаешь в субботу у меня работа, к сожалению, я не смогу прийти',
        audio: 'audio/аудио6.mp3',
        speaker: 2,
        id: 6,
        prompt:
          'Say that: You know what, on Saturday I have football, unfortunately, I cannot come',
        helpers: [
          {
            word_mother: 'You know what!',
            word_target: 'Ты знаешь!'
          },
          {
            word_mother: 'Unfortunately!',
            word_target: 'К сожалению!'
          },
          {
            word_mother: 'Cannot',
            word_target: 'Не могу'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        text: 'Тогда как насчет воскресенья',
        audio: 'audio/аудио7.mp3',
        speaker: 1,
        prompt: '',
        id: 7,
        helpers: [
          {
            word_mother: 'Then',
            word_target: 'Тогда'
          },
          {
            word_mother: 'How about',
            word_target: 'Как насчет'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        text:
          'Да, давай увидимся в Воскресенье, как раз, у буду свободен весь день',
        audio: 'audio/аудио8.mp3',
        speaker: 2,
        id: 8,
        prompt:
          "Tell your partner: Yes, let's meet on Sunday, it just so happens that, I will be free on Sunday the entire day",
        helpers: [
          {
            word_mother: "Let's meet",
            word_target: 'Давай увидимся'
          },
          {
            word_mother: 'It just so happens that',
            word_target: 'Как раз'
          },
          {
            word_mother: 'I will be free',
            word_target: 'Я буду свободным'
          },
          {
            word_mother: 'The entire day',
            word_target: 'Весь день'
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 'dialogue2',
    parts: [
      {
        text: `как ты?`,
        audio: 'audio/аудио1.mp3',
        prompt: '',
        speaker: 1,
        id: 1
      },
      {
        text: 'все хорошо, а как ты?',
        audio: 'audio/аудио2.mp3',
        prompt: 'Say that: I am OK, how about you?',
        speaker: 2,
        id: 2,
        helpers: [
          {
            word_mother: "I'm all right",
            word_target: 'У меня все хорошо'
          },
          {
            word_mother: 'And you?',
            word_target: 'А как ты?'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        text: 'у меня тоже неплохо, кстати а что ты делаешь в субботу',
        audio: 'audio/аудио3.mp3',
        prompt: '',
        speaker: 1,
        id: 3,
        helpers: [
          {
            word_mother: 'Not bad',
            word_target: 'неплохо'
          },
          {
            word_mother: 'By the way',
            word_target: 'Кстати'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        text: 'в субботу у меня футбол, а что?',
        audio: 'audio/аудио4.mp3',
        speaker: 2,
        prompt: 'Say that: I have football on Saturday, why are you asking?',
        id: 4,
        helpers: [
          {
            word_mother: 'Why are you asking?',
            word_target: 'А что?'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        text: 'Просто я хотел пригласить тебя на день рождения',
        audio: 'audio/аудио5.mp3',
        speaker: 1,
        prompt: '',
        id: 5,
        helpers: [
          {
            word_mother: 'Just',
            word_target: 'Просто'
          },
          {
            word_mother: 'Wanted',
            word_target: 'Хотел (past simple form)'
          },
          {
            word_mother: 'To invite',
            word_target: 'Пригласить'
          },
          {
            word_mother: 'Birthday',
            word_target: 'День рождения'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        text:
          'Ты знаешь в субботу у меня работа, к сожалению, я не смогу прийти',
        audio: 'audio/аудио6.mp3',
        speaker: 2,
        id: 6,
        prompt:
          'Say that: You know what, on Saturday I have football, unfortunately, I cannot come',
        helpers: [
          {
            word_mother: 'You know what!',
            word_target: 'Ты знаешь!'
          },
          {
            word_mother: 'Unfortunately!',
            word_target: 'К сожалению!'
          },
          {
            word_mother: 'Cannot',
            word_target: 'Не могу'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        text: 'Тогда как насчет воскресенья',
        audio: 'audio/аудио7.mp3',
        speaker: 1,
        prompt: '',
        id: 7,
        helpers: [
          {
            word_mother: 'Then',
            word_target: 'Тогда'
          },
          {
            word_mother: 'How about',
            word_target: 'Как насчет'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        text:
          'Да, давай увидимся в Воскресенье, как раз, у буду свободен весь день',
        audio: 'audio/аудио8.mp3',
        speaker: 2,
        id: 8,
        prompt:
          "Tell your partner: Yes, let's meet on Sunday, it just so happens that, I will be free on Sunday the entire day",
        helpers: [
          {
            word_mother: "Let's meet",
            word_target: 'Давай увидимся'
          },
          {
            word_mother: 'It just so happens that',
            word_target: 'Как раз'
          },
          {
            word_mother: 'I will be free',
            word_target: 'Я буду свободным'
          },
          {
            word_mother: 'The entire day',
            word_target: 'Весь день'
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];

export default lines;
```

Comment: is `lines` an array or an object? can you log `console.log('logID', typeof lines, lines)`?

Comment: lines is array of objects

Comment: other objects aka 'dialogues' render fine.

Comment: based on this line `lines={this.findDialogue(routeProps.match.params.id)}`, you are using `.find()` method, which will return an object I assume?

Comment: Ok, apparently my lines array does not change, but dialogue object does. What is wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to achieve here (what is your use case?), but maybe try to refactor `this.findDialogue()` method to return an array instead?

Comment: I have added prepopulated lines array, which is populated with new objects through form, please, could you take a look? Maybe this is a source of the issue?

Comment: can you create a codepen or sandbox for me to review?

Comment: I never did it but I will try. Let you know, thanks!

Comment: try this: https://codesandbox.io

Comment: Ok, good, it will probably take some time.

Comment: Hi @JeeMok, please take a look at my project in sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-cdn-4ym2j

Comment: Hi @NZMAI did you forgot to save? I see a lot of empty file

Comment: Hi @JeeMok, I guess I have updated the project, let me send you the link again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197252/discussion-between-nzmai-and-jee-mok).

Answer (score 0):

the `findDialogue()` method uses `.find()` method which will return an object (if found) or `undefined`.

```
  findDialogue(id) {
    return this.state.dialogues.find(function(dialogue) {
      return dialogue.id === id;
    });
  }
```

maybe you can use `.filter()` or `.map()` to return an array? or do `lines={this.state.dialogues}` (depends on your requirement)

```
              <Route
                exact
                path="/dialogue/:id"
                render={routeProps => (
                  <BubbleSpeechFrame
                    lines={this.state.dialogues}
                  />
                )}
              />
```